# How to create an incrementing pattern with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

There are 4 columns in a chart that tracks how much money you would need to spend to "guarantee" you end with more money than you spent on the round you do potentially win.

[image]

There are six different bets you can make with 6 respective prizes I have in arrays:

`var bets = [5,10,28,50,56,280]` , `var prizes = [40,80,250,400,500,2500]`.
So a bet of **5** would win a prize of **40** and so on.

The first step is to find the lowest possible sum of bets above `totalSpent`. which starts at `0`. The function would find **5** and make that equal the value `spentPerRound`.

[image]

Find the prize(s) associated with the bet(s):

[image]

Update totalSpent. **5** was spent:

[image]

Result = prize - totalSpent.

[image]

There's a few caveats which complicates things a little bit. One, `result` must always be a positive number or 0. Two, finding the lowest possible sum above `totalSpent` means finding the lowest possible number created only using sums of values from the `bets` array. Values can be repeated and used more than once. The chart continued:

[image]

I attempt:

```js
var totalSpent = 0;
var spentPerGame = 0;
var bets = [5,10,28,50,56,280];
var prizes = [40,80,250,400,500,2500];
  
function findSpentPerGame(){
  var candidates = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < bets.length; i++ ){
    if( bets[ i ] > totalSpent ){
      spentPerGame = bets[ i ];
      break;//done. You found it.
    }
    else{
      var x = bets[ i ] + bets[ i ];
      if( x > totalSpent ){
        spentPerGame = x; break; //done
      }
      else{
        for( var iA = 0; iA < bets.length; iA++ ){
          if( bets[ iA ] == x ){
            var z = x; break;
          }
        }
        if( z + bets[ i ] > totalSpent ){
          //spentPerGame = z?     
        }
      }
    }
  }
  totalSpent = parseInt( candidates );
  totalSpent = totalSpent + spentPerGame;;
  return spentPerGame;
}

for( var i = 1; i <= 300; i++ ){
  document.querySelector( 'tbody' ).innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + i + 
    '</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>';
}
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center
}
td, th{
  border:1px solid black; padding:10px; font-family:Arial
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ROUND</th><th>TOTAL SPENT</th><th>SPENT / ROUND</th>
      <th>COMPONENTS OF SPENT / ROUND</th><th>PRIZE</th><th>RESULT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the question? Which part is troubling you exactly?

Comment: @MattWay The first step. Finding `SpentPerGame`.

Comment: is the z in the if(...) the same z defined locally  within the loop ?